# Save hundreds of nodes in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

The company I work for is managing a pretty big website in Drupal 8 and Mysql for a client.

Every 5 minutes via cron we import a lot of data (between 100 and 1000s) that generates contents in a custom entity type (similar to the node entity). The website receives something like 300 pageviews a minute during the process.

We are having trouble with the Entity::create/Entity::save methods because our mysql start returning "SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock" at some point in the save process.
Is there any better way to save a lot of contents?

We don't think the problem is the server performance (8 cores and 8GB of RAM). Also the Mysql has been tuned with different tools.

Comment: I add a first answer about bulk operations. But, if you show us more of your code, we could help you to improve performances & fix your bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the [MySQL Transactions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx). Drupal 8 support them very well with the [Transaction class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Transaction.php/class/Transaction/8.5.x) usable with both `database` or any `storage` services.

---

Here an example for creation of more than 2'000 of nodes, one after each other.

```
// Load services, should be injected in your Class/Service.

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection $connection */
$connection = \Drupal::service('database');

/** @var \Drupal\node\NodeStorageInterface $nodeStorage */
$nodeStorage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger */
$logger = \Drupal::service('logger.factory')->get('import-nodes');

// Save every node using transaction to avoid corruptions or MySQL failover on bulk creation.
$transaction = $connection->startTransaction();

// Nodes to be updated, up to thousands, change the code here.
$nodes = [
  3038 => [
    'title' => uniqid(),
  ],
  3039 => [
    'title' => uniqid(),
  ],
  // ...
];

try {
  foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    $new_node = $nodeStorage->create([
      'type'   => 'page',
      'bundle' => 'node',
      'title'  => $node['title'],
    ]);
    $new_node->save();
  }
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  $transaction->rollback();
  $logger->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

You will need to adapte the code to retrieve `$nodes` & the `$new_node` values.

---

Using Transactions will allow you to ensure database integrity throught safe rollback. E.g. when your script fails (for any reasons) the transactions will rollback in the `try-catch` statement.

To go further, take a look to the [Batch API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview) (UI bulk operations with Ajax), [Batch API example](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/batch-process-drupal-8) & the [Queue Worker/API](https://knackforge.com/blog/vamsi/how-create-queue-woker-drupal-8) (backend bulk operations with cron).

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what I need is a way to allow mySql to process all the contents without breaking, for example by making a single commit of the transaction. If I use the method you suggested the new nodes aren't saved if even one of them fails. I need them not to fail. Do you know if is it possible to use something like Doctrine commit()? Thank you.

Comment: You can move the try catch around every save instead of the whole foreach. So it will rollback only the last failed one. Does it help you ?

Comment: this is good, but is there a way in drupal to build create all nodes with one save query.
Like a Array of values set in a insert into condition.